# Is "I always call back when I missed the call" correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

> 1. I always call back when I missed the call.
> 2. I always call you back when I missed your call.

Is this right sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The correct tense to use is the **simple present**.  In English, that is the tense used for [habitual actions](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/). Since you say *always*, you are indicating that this is a standard action, hence the simple present is correct.

> I always call back when I *miss* your calls.

Further, the tense of the second verb needs to match the first. Consider these two:

> "What happened when you missed the call?
>   "I called back."

This is a one-time event. You missed a specific call, and you called back. But if the question is about what you customarily do, both the question and the answer should be in the simple present:

> "What happens when you miss a call?"
>   "I call back."

*Whenever* you miss any call, you call back. This is the general state of things, and therefore takes the simple present. Since it is general and not specific, you also should use *a call* rather than *the call*.  The definite article indicates some particular call, not calls in general.

But you are talking only about calls from the person you are talking to.  You call back when you miss a call from that person, not necessarily from others. So you need to specify that. You can do that by saying either *your calls* (because there have been, and will be, multiple calls, which is plural) or *a call from you* (because you are talking about *any given* call, which is singular).